# WebIDE Firefox OS Simulator Operation Failed: connecting to runtime

Tags: firefox, firefox-os, b2g

Complete noob at this. Trying to get Firefox OS simulator working to learn to write apps for Firefox OS. Running openSUSE 13.2.  I cannot start the simulator.

I install Firefox 34.0.5, I enable verbose logging for Firefox OS 1.3 and 1.4 as described here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Firefox_OS_Simulator

I open WebIDE, goto Select Runtime and Install Simulator, I select 1.3 or 1.4 and install.
(I have also tried installing directly from: https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/labs/fxos-simulator/)
Either way, the Firefox 1.3/1.4 is listed in WebIDE under Select Runtime.

I try to run the simulator by clicking on Firefox 1.3 or 1.4 under Select Runtime on WebIDE.

I get a spinner icon on WebIDE, after a period of time I get an error message:

```
Operation failed: connecting to runtime.
```

There is a troubleshooting button, I don't find any useful help there. I'm probably missing something obvious but I can't see it.

Browser Console logging shows:

```
"subprocess: getlimit: maxFD=1024" simulator-process.js:35
"subprocess: subprocess started; got PID 3533" simulator-process.js:35
"Connection status changed: connecting" app-manager.js:127
"subprocess: Got msg from stdout: initialising library with libc.so.6" simulator-process.js:35
"subprocess: Got msg from stdout: waitpid signaled subprocess stop, exitcode=256" simulator-process.js:35
"subprocess: Got msg from stdout: poll returned HUP" simulator-process.js:35
"subprocess: Pipe stdout closed" simulator-process.js:35
"subprocess: Got msg from stderr: initialising library with libc.so.6" simulator-process.js:35
"subprocess: Got msg from stderr: reading next chunk" simulator-process.js:35
"subprocess: got 146 bytes from stderr" simulator-process.js:35
"subprocess: Got msg from stderr: poll returned HUP" simulator-process.js:35
"subprocess: Pipe stderr closed" simulator-process.js:35
"subprocess: Cleanup called" simulator-process.js:35
"subprocess: trying to close stdin" simulator-process.js:35
"subprocess: Closing Stdin" simulator-process.js:35
"(process:3533): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion 'sys_page_size == 0' failed
No protocol specified
Error: cannot open display: :0" simulator-process.js:44
"b2g-bin terminated with 0" simulator-process.js:107
"Connection status changed: disconnecting" app-manager.js:127
TypeError: this._client is null
Stack trace:
Connection.prototype.disconnect@resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js ->     resource://gre/modules/devtools/client/connection-manager.js:186:7
Connection.prototype._onTimeout@resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://gre/modules/devtools/client/connection-manager.js:285:5
notify@resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/timers.js:40:9
timers.js:43
"Connection status changed: disconnected" app-manager.js:127
"Operation failed: connecting to runtime" webide.js:274
UI.reportError() webide.js:274
UI.busyUntil/<() webide.js:257
Handler.prototype.process() Promise-backend.js:868
this.PromiseWalker.walkerLoop() Promise-backend.js:744

undefined webide.js:258
UI.busyUntil/<() webide.js:258
Handler.prototype.process() Promise-backend.js:868
this.PromiseWalker.walkerLoop() Promise-backend.js:744
```

Answer (score 2):

After trying to get this working for days, I took a break and tried again today.

I found a similar problem affecting NixOS users:
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=980437

which lead to:
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1031100

It is a X server security problem.  Fixed with

```
xhost +
```

Then run firefox.   This info has been posted in case others have a similar problem.

Comment: If you must disable access control with this command, I would suggest only doing it before you want to use the simulator and run `xhost -` after to reinstate the access controls.

Comment: Yes, agreed.  I should have said that rather than assume people would just do that, thanks.

Comment: i have this same problem on **fedora22**. thanks alot for your share.